# Execute Makefile target only if dependencies needed building

Tags: makefile

I have a project with two "subprojects" and a Dockerfile that combines the executables from each subproject.  The directory structure is like this:

```
Makefile
Dockerfile
proj1/Makefile
proj1/proj1-bin
proj1/...
proj2/Makefile
proj2/proj1-bin
proj2/...
```

My top level Makefile is currently like this:

```
container: proj1 proj2
  docker build .

proj1:
  make -C proj1

proj2:
  make -C proj2

.PHONY: container proj1 proj2
```

How can I make it so the container is only rebuilt if proj1 or proj2 was rebuilt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a target is marked as `.PHONY`, it will always be rebuilt, so the first thing is to get rid of phony targets and depend on actual files, which have timestamps to be compared. The only thing is how to find out that a container has been built; one way of dealing with that is to create a timestamp file whenever the container is built - this will only serve as a timestamp for `make` to compare when deciding whether to rebuild target.

The timestamp file should depend on actual files that are created in subprojects, so that docker build timestamp is compared with the actual binaries and if actual binaries are newer, the container will be rebuilt. Subprojects in turn need to always be delegated to `$(MAKE)` as only sub-Makefile will know how and if to rebuild the target. We can achieve that by depending on a phony target, which will make the recipe run, but in the end, if the file itself did not get updated, it will not trigger rebuild of higher level target (`container.timestamp` file, hence the container will not be rebuilt).

Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: container
container: container.timestamp

container.timestamp: proj1/proj1.bin proj2/proj2.bin
        echo docker build .
        touch $@

%.bin: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C $(@D)

.PHONY: FORCE

$ cat proj1/Makefile
proj1.bin:
        touch $@

$ cat proj2/Makefile
proj2.bin:
        touch $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
make -C proj1
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
touch proj1.bin
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
make -C proj2
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
touch proj2.bin
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
echo docker build .
docker build .
touch container.timestamp

$ make
make -C proj1
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
make[1]: 'proj1.bin' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
make -C proj2
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
make[1]: 'proj2.bin' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
```

Note how sub-makefiles were called, but since the binaries were not updated, the container was not updated either. If, however, this got update, the container would be rebuilt:

```
$ touch proj2/proj2.bin
$ make
make -C proj1
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
make[1]: 'proj1.bin' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj1'
make -C proj2
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
make[1]: 'proj2.bin' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/raspy/git/so-68290730/proj2'
echo docker build .
docker build .
touch container.timestamp
```